# How to open ports to in Apps hosted on Azure Linux App Service

Tags: linux, azure, port, email, azure-web-app-service

On Azure Linux App Service plan how to open ports to use SendGrid or other email services with Apps

None of my sites can send emails. I have tried configuring to use phpmail, sendmail, and smtp thought SendGrid. Non of these options work I ran the below code to TS the issue.

```
<?php
$array = array(8080, 80, 25, 587, 465);

foreach ($array as &$port) {
    $fp = fsockopen('127.0.0.1', $port, $errno, $errstr, 5);
    if (!$fp) {
       echo "Port is closed:";
       echo $port;
    } else {
       echo "Port is open:";
       echo $port;
        fclose($fp);
    }
    echo "<br>";
}
?>
```

This is the output:

```
Port is open:8080
Port is closed:80
Port is closed:25
Port is closed:587
Port is closed:465
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Azure Linux App Service plan, Do you mean  Azure App Service Web App on Linux? If yes, currently you only could open one ports. Please refer to this [FAQ](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service-web/app-service-linux-faq#custom-containers).

> Q: I want to expose more than one port on my custom container image.
>   Is that possible?
>
> A: Currently, that isn't supported.

If you want to open multiple ports, you could select Azure VMs.

Comment: This seams a bit shortsighted on there part. I have not seen a modern day website that did not have some form of contact form on it.

Comment: @JCPhlux Sorry, I don't know what do you mean?

Comment: I am a bit raw on php and Linux (more of a .net guy). This is a site that I got from a hosting company that went under. I thought it would be a good candidate to host on Linux as that is what it was on before but on rackspace. On the last server it used phpmail to send contact messages. I am unable to connect to SMTP server to sent contact form emails.

Comment: Yes, based on my knowledge, a mail server should be hosted on a VM. For Azure App Service Web App on Linux, you need open multiple ports. But, it does not support this.

Comment: This is sad. I have never seen a well made site that did not have a contact form so this one decision by the azure team is detrimental to this product being viable to anyone.